# Firebase createUser authentication error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, firebase, firebase-security

So I'm having the weirdest problem with the firebase simple authentication...

When I visit `localhost/#register`, fill out the form, then submit it, I get a `SERVER_ERROR` in the `authClient.createUser()` callback. But when I **refresh** the page and fill in the form again, it works!

**This happens without fail every time I restart my server and try to register a user.**

To reiterate, the first time I execute it I get a server error, but after I refresh the page everything works like a charm... This leads me to think that I'm including the firebase scripts incorrectly, and all the necessary files don't get included until the refresh, but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

**UPDATE:** I get this error when I submit the form (starred out for privacy):

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-demo.firebaseio-demo.com/.ws?**********************' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

And the errors come from `firebase.js` lines 51 - 63.

**Stack**
 - brunch.io with backbone-marionette. Basically it's a gruntJS build with coffee-script and a commonJS wrapper for really simple frontend modularity.

**index.html** - where I include the scripts

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Brunch with Marionette</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <!-- CSS and font-awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Grunt compiled scripts -->
  <script src="javascripts/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>

  <!-- Firebase scripts -->
    <script src="javascripts/backbone-firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js'></script>

  <!-- Start application -->
  <script>
        require('initialize');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**RegisterView.coffee** - where I create the authClient and try to create a new firebase registered user (the backbone model gets added to the `UserList` collection correctly, which then syncs with the database correctly, the only problem is with `createUser()`)

```
template = require './templates/register'
User = require '../models/user'

user = new User()

module.exports = class RegisterView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
    id: 'register-view'
    template: template
    model: user

    initialize: ->
        this.form = $(this.el).find('form#account')
        base = new Firebase("https://***********.firebaseIO-demo.com/")
        this.authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient base, 
            (error, user_cb)->
                if (error)
                    console.log(error)
                else if (user_cb)
                    console.log('User ID: ' + user_cd.id + ', Provider: ' + user_cb.provider)
                else
                                    # This is currently what gets executed, 
                                    # which I'm pretty sure is correct behavior
                    console.log('logged out')
    events: 
        'submit form': 'on_submit'
        'blur #first_name' : 'check_first'
        'blur #last_name' : 'check_last'
        'blur #email' : 'check_email'
        'blur #password' : 'check_password'
        'blur #confirm_password' : 'check_confirm_password'

    on_submit: (e)->
        this.add_user()

    check_first: (e)->

    check_last: (e)->

    check_email: (e)->

    check_password: (e)->

    check_confirm_password: (e)->

    add_user: (e)->
        form = $(this.el).find('form#account')

        user.set({
        first_name : form.find('#first_name').val()
        last_name : form.find('#last_name').val()
        email : form.find('#email').val()
        password: form.find('#password').val()
    })
    window.UserList.add(user)

    email = form.find('#email').val()
    password = form.find('#password').val()

        this.authClient.createUser(email, password, 
            (error, user)->
                if (error)
                    console.log(error)
                if (!error)
                    console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email)
        )
```

**UPDATE:** I tried changing the server from `-demo` to a production one, but it made no difference.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using the -demo server for any of this. Auth / security doesn't work on the demo server. Use the production server. Are the errors any different with the production server?

Comment: I get the same error when I use the production server